# Modify RDS change Microsoft SQL Server license type

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm about to set up Microsoft SQL Server on RDS.
In the future we are going to use Standard License to get advantage of Multi-AZ replication. But we want to avoid costs in the earlier stage and go with Express Edition for now.

Is it possible to modify RDS and change license from Express to Standard later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone else is looking for the answer. I got reply from aws support:

It would not be possible to change your SQL Server licence from Express to Standard by modifying the RDS instance. If you would like to upgrade your SQL Server instance to begin using Standard Edition, you will need to take a snapshot of the Express Edition instance, and restore it as a new instance using Standard Edition.

I would be happy to outline a way you can do this below:

1. Take a snapshot of your SQL Server DB instance that you want to
   upgrade to Standard Edition. If you are unsure on how to do this, I
   can provide this documentation which explains how to do this:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html
2. When the snapshot has been created select the snapshot and click 'Actions', then click 'Restore Snapshot'.
3. Next, you will be brought to the Restore Snapshot screen. Under the DB engine heading, you can then select 'Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition' option.
4. When you are happy with the configuration of the new Standard Edition instance, click 'Restore DB Instance'.